# "XCode" would like to access your contacts

Tags: xcode, version-control, contacts, xcode7.1

I launched XCode 7.1, and noticed XCode wants to access my Phonebook contacts. I can see it can connect with the collaborators, but not able to get through it completely.

1. What kind of pairing will it do?
2. Do i need to share my username with my co-collaborators? Or as a part of same organization, XCode will share the details automatically?

[image: XCode 7.1]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just say No.  It can mind its own business.

Comment: After telling Xcode 9.2 "Don't allow" it would no longer let me commit files. Quitting and restarting Xcode fixed that however.